# regexp exclusion

Tags: regex, exception

I have regexp to change smileys to images. Here it is

```
(?:(?![0]:\)|:\)\)|:-\)\)))(:\)|:-\))
```

The point is not to change 0:) and :)) and :-)) while changing :) and :-)
It works pretty well with :)) and :-)) but somehow still grabs :) in 0:)

Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want to match `:)` and `:-)`, but they must not be preceded by `0` or followed by another `)`? Then this is the pattern:

```
(?<!0):-?\)(?!\))
```

Basically it's

```
(?<!0) : negative lookbehind; must not be preceded by 0
:-?\)  : smiley with optional nose
(?!\)) : negative lookforward; must not be followed by )
```

Example:

```
$ echo ':) :-) ok 0:) :)) :-)) 0:-)) 0:-) : )' | \
> perl -lne'print $1 while /(?<!0)(:-?\))(?!\))/g'
:)
:-)
```